# Create infinite number of nested folders using infinite loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, mkdir

I am working on a small project. The task is to create a bash script that will create infinite number of folders when clicked, and inside each folder, it creates infinite number of folders in each folder and so on. For example,

- Folder1

  - SubFolder1
    SubFolder2
    SubFolder3
    ...
    SubFolder∞

    - SubSubFolder1
      SubSubFolder2
      SubSubFolder3
      ...
      SubSubFolder∞

      - SubSubSubFolder1
        SubSubSubFolder2
        SubSubSubFolder3
        ...
        SubSubSubFolder∞
- ...
- Folder∞

  - SubFolder1
    SubFolder2
    SubFolder3
    ...
    SubFolder∞

    - SubSubFolder1
      SubSubFolder2
      SubSubFolder3
      ...
      SubSubFolder∞

      - SubSubSubFolder1
        SubSubSubFolder2
        SubSubSubFolder3
        ...
        SubSubSubFolder∞

The sequence is like this:

Folder 1 has infinite folders (SubFolder1, SubFolder2, ..., SubFolder∞). The first folder(SubFolder1) has further sub folders (SubSubFolder1, ..., SubSubFolder∞). The SubSubFolder1 has further subfolders (SubSubSubFolder1, ... SubSubSubFolder∞) and so on. Similar for Folder2 and its sub folders.

I tested the script for 10 folders. It created 10 top-level folders. In each folder, it created 10 subfolders each. But it stopped there, I want it to run continuously (infinite loop). Also, it works sequentially (it will create 10 subfolders in Folder1, then comeout and create Folder2, and its sub folders and so on), I want it continuous (make Folder1 and its subfolders continuously with Folder2 and its subfolders and so on). The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the number of outer and inner directories to create
num_outer=10
num_inner=10

# Create the outer loop
for ((i=0; i<num_outer; i++))
do
  # Create a new outer directory with a unique name
  mkdir "outer_folder_$i"

  # Navigate into the new outer directory
  cd "outer_folder_$i"

  # Create the inner loop
  for ((j=0; j<num_inner; j++))
  do
    # Create a new inner directory with a unique name
    mkdir "inner_folder_$j"
  done

  # Navigate back to the parent directory
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: Sounds like a fork bomb eh?

Comment: The operating system will shut you down before you get anywhere infinite. There are limits on overall path length, on total number of inodes (which includes directories) on a filesystem, on number of directories (though on some filesystems that's a limit that's larger than the inode count, "infinite" is pretty big). Also, the integer arithmetic that the shell supports has a fixed maximum integer size it can handle; there's no "infinite" there either.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you just want to make `i<num_outer` always true so the loop never finishes, then... err, replace it with an operation that's always true instead of enforcing a `num_outer` limit. Or switch from a `for` loop to a `while`, or do whatever else you happen to prefer.

Comment: (And if you want to follow multiple paths at once, as always, `somecommand &` runs `somecommand` in the background so the rest of your script can keep going in the foreground; move your logic into a function, start copies of that function in the background, and there you are -- though it _will_ devolve very quickly into a fork bomb, which is probably a lot less interesting than whatever you actually intended)

Comment: What's your question? Please read [ask]. What you're describing is not possible, as Charles said, so it's not clear what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rekfolder.sh script does not produce an infinite number of directories, because the constant flow of new harddrives would be too expensive for me, but about x! (x fac) numbers of directories, where x is is given as a command line parameter and counted downwards in each recursive step.

Start it like this:

```
timeout -k 5 3s ./rekfolder.sh f 8
```

which stops the script after 3s and - if things go wrong - kills it after 5. f will be the name part of the starting dir.

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
count=$2

# save my harddrive!
if (( ${#name} > 25 ))
then
    echo err namelength
    exit 0
elif (( count == 0 ))
then
    echo err count
    exit 0
else
    # Set the number of directories to create
    num=3
    name=$name

    for ((i=0; i<count; i++))
    do
        # save my harddrive again
        sleep 0.3
        echo mkdir ${name}$i
        mkdir ${name}$i
        ./rekfolder.sh ${name}$i/ $((count-1)) &
    done
fi
```

This produced 109600 directories. The sleep is in there, to allow to interrupt the process of exponential growth with a `killall rekfolder.sh` in a second terminal, but it's getting hard, if you don't interrupt early.

You may delete all those folders, if they are created in a fresh dir, with

```
  find -type d -delete
```

(took me about a second (SSD)).

Note that there is much trailing output, long after finishing all the ./rekfolder.sh scripts, which makes it look, as if the `timeout` does not work. You may observe the processes in a second terminal

```
for i in {1..10}
do 
    ps -C rekfolder.sh
    sleep 1
done
```